# What is the difference between get_object and get_connections in Koala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am having troubles understanding how to use the Koala gem. I couldn't understand when to use get_object and when should I use get_connections. what is the difference between them and in which cases should I use each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

On that first page you see the me/ connection by default.  This is like calling `get_object("me")`.

On the explorer, on the right side of the page, there's a **Connections** grouping.  Click on interests (or any of them).  What you see now is like calling `get_connections("me","interests")`.